# Parallelize calling of object methods

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a list of objects and for each of them I want to call their foo function, passing it the argument bar. I want to parallelize this operation, so right now I'm looking at using Pool.map from the multiprocessing package. I'm not sure how to use map to run an object method, though. How can I do that? Or is there a better way to do this in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a helper function and pass the object method and its arguments to that function via `Pool.map`. The helper function would look something like this:

```
def helper(*args):
    return args[0](*args[1:])
```

And you would use it like this:

```
pool = Pool()
results = pool.map(helper, [obj.method, arg1, arg2])
```

Note that the helper function must be directly importable from its containing module.